# Calculate time between rows

Tags: sql, datetime

Table dbo.Update includes a datetime of when the update took place along with an entered by person ID.

In my result set i need to include the time of the update and who created the update but also the time since the previous update

eg;

```
ID    Datetime     Person     Time Between
1     0900hrs      1          -
2     0947hrs      2          47m
3     1030hrs      1          43m
```

The number of rows in dbo.Update will vary and the differences could go in to days or even weeks sometimes.

I cant figure out how to do this if someone could possibly assit?

Thanks in Advance!

~D

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempts. What worked, what's not working? BTW you have asked several questions with answers but no up-votes. Please reward your helpers.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax suggests that you are using SQL Server.  In SQL Server 2012+, just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(minute, lag(datetime) over (order by datetime), datetime) as diff_in_minutes
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks i just stumbled upon something similar - works a treat            SELECT  q.*,  DATEDIFF(second, pDiff, DateField)
FROM    (


        SELECT  *,
                LAG(DateField) OVER (ORDER BY DateField) pDiff
        FROM    dbo.Table 
        ) q